# The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I am using an anonymous function with async and the error occurred while compilation. I am calling this function inside a parent function as await.

I have two functions:

1. parent function
2. child function

in parent function, I am using async-await. and called second function (which is arrow function). if i write that function as `async function functionName (parameters) {}` it works, but i am using it as `export const functionName = async (params) => {}` and it gave me this error.

```
const a = await b(data);

const b = async (data) => { return "success" }
```

i try to add `const functionName = async (params) Promise<string> => {}` but still same error.

In parent function, I am calling child function as,

how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining return type of method you need to add `:`
And also you need to specify the type of what will the promise return

```
const functionName = async (params): Promise<any> => {}
```

Comment: i did that too const functionName = async (params): Promise<any> => {} still error occurred.

Comment: @AmitChauhan well yes. if you define that function but keep body empty like ```{}``` you will get error because you defined that the function will return promise but you are not returning anything

Comment: that was just to make you understand we can take return true there.